# LibGDX incorrectly animating model with bone constraints

Tags: animation, libgdx, blender, fbx

I have loaded an animated Blender model into LibGDX, but it is not displaying correctly. It is difficult to tell exactly what is happening. Just taking a guess, the pieces of my model seem to be rotating in both world space and local space.

Here are GIF animations of how it should look and how it appears in LibGDX:

**The correct blender version:**
[image: Correct Blender version]

**The incorrect LibGDX version:**
[image: Incorrect LibGDX version]

I'm really not sure where to start with this problem. I am using several different bone constraints, and I assume this might be the cause. Does LibGDX, fbx-conv, or even the .fbx file format simply not support certain blender constraints.

Here are just the relevant portions of my LibGDX code, in case I did something wrong:

**Animation setup code:**

```
Model model = assetManager.get("pump.g3db", Model.class);
instance = new ModelInstance(model);
instances.add( instance );

// Run all animations on a loop
for( Animation animation : instance.animations ) {
    AnimationController controller = new AnimationController( instance );
    controller.setAnimation( animation.id, -1 );
    animationControllers.add( controller );
}
```

**Render loop code:**

```
Iterator<AnimationController> acIteratore = animationControllers.iterator();
while ( acIteratore.hasNext() ){
    AnimationController ac = acIteratore.next();
    ac.update( Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() );
}
```

Here is the `.blend` file, if anyone wants to look at the armature and constraints:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31195

Anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem, or at least what the cause might be?

Comment: Why are you using multiple animations for that?

Comment: In Blender, the only animation is the rotation of a single object. Then using constraints, the other objects also move. After exporting to FBX and running the model through fbx-conv the animation is broken into a separate animation for each object. In other words, the animation IDs follow this format: `"MyObject|MyAnimation"`, `"MyOtherObject|MyAnimation"`, etc.

Comment: I don't know blender, but I'm pretty sure that it allows multiple node transformation in a single animation. Which is pretty common for e.g. armature animations.

Comment: That's the problem. As far as I know, I am using a single animation in blender. It seems that the export process splits it into multiple animations though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was caused by my settings on Blender's FBX exporter. To fix the problem, turn off the following two setting:

- `NLA Strips`
- `All Actions`

An explanation of these setting can be found on this page, under "Baked animation": http://code.blender.org/index.php/2014/06/supporting-game-developers-with-blender-2-71/

Here is a screenshot with the settings to be turned off outlined in red:
[image: Bad settings]

*This answer is only relevant to Blender 2.71 or higher(probably)*